# Python - Como dividir un dict en grupos y sumar las cantidades de cada uno de ellos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Python y por más que busco info no se como resolver este tema:
Lo que necesito hacer es tomar todos los datos de **bids** en **dataOrderbook**, **agrupar por precios de 50 en 50 y que se sumen las cantidades**, lograr algo así:

**Precio**------------------------------------------------//------------**Cantidad**--------------------------
28950 (engloba los precios desde 28950 a 29000 //suma de cantidades de los precios englobados-
28900 (28918.20, , 28948.90 etc)-------------------//---------                        3.23 + 8.022 + 0.658 + etc----------------
28850 y así hasta el final--------------------------// " " " "

Los datos de partida son un dict:

```
dataOrderbook = {'lastUpdateId': 1552049131602, 'E': 1653776319293,
 'T': 1653776319280, 'bids': [['28962.00', '17.682'], ['28961.90',
 '5.011'], ['28961.60', '0.452'], ['28961.50', '2.887'], ['28949.10', '0.036'], ['28948.90', '2.007'], ['28948.80', '0.500'], ['28948.70',
'0.001'], ['28918.20', '0.016'], ['28918.10', '0.191'], ['28918.00',
'0.019'], ['28917.90', '0.001'], ['28855.90', '0.086'], ['28855.80',
'0.001'], ['28855.60', '0.018'], ['28855.50', '0.010'], 'asks':
[['28962.10', '0.008'], ['28962.40', '0.002'], ['28962.70', '0.001'],
['28963.20', '0.165'], ['29000.30', '0.045'], ['29000.40', '1.228'],
['29000.50', '0.606'], ['29000.60', '1.500'], ['29051.70', '0.011'],
['29051.80', '0.025'], ['29052.00', '1.951'], ['29052.10', '0.068'],
['29101.40', '1.411'], ['29101.50', '0.019'], ['29101.60', '0.002'],
['29101.70', '0.001'],]}

orderbook = pd.DataFrame(dataOrderbook, columns=['bids', 'asks'])

#orderbook -> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

#con los los anteriores datos separo dos conjuntos: bids con precio/cantidad y asks igual:

#formattedBids -> list

formattedBids = [[float(price), float(quantity)] for price, quantity in orderbook['bids']]

formattedAsks = [[float(price), float(quantity)] for price, quantity in orderbook['asks']]
```

Llego a estas dos list y no se como continuar. Tampoco se si debería convertir dict en dataframe o list como para lograr lo que me propongo.

Espero haber explicado bien mi problema y agradezco toda ayuda que me permita continuar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

El método [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) es lo que necesitas para poder dividir en rangos

Teniendo el siguiente `dataframe` llamado `orderbook` (Creado según tus datos)

```
    bids                asks
0   [28962.00, 17.682]  [28962.10, 0.008]
1   [28961.90, 5.011]   [28962.40, 0.002]
2   [28961.60, 0.452]   [28962.70, 0.001]
3   [28961.50, 2.887]   [28963.20, 0.165]
4   [28949.10, 0.036]   [29000.30, 0.045]
5   [28948.90, 2.007]   [29000.40, 1.228]
6   [28948.80, 0.500]   [29000.50, 0.606]
7   [28948.70, 0.001]   [29000.60, 1.500]
8   [28918.20, 0.016]   [29051.70, 0.011]
9   [28918.10, 0.191]   [29051.80, 0.025]
10  [28918.00, 0.019]   [29052.00, 1.951]
11  [28917.90, 0.001]   [29052.10, 0.068]
12  [28855.90, 0.086]   [29101.40, 1.411]
13  [28855.80, 0.001]   [29101.50, 0.019]
14  [28855.60, 0.018]   [29101.60, 0.002]
15  [28855.50, 0.010]   [29101.70, 0.001]
```

Obtenemos `bids` en un `dataframe` aparte y nos aseguramos que las columnas sean de tipo `float64`

```
bids = pd.DataFrame(orderbook['bids'].tolist(), columns=['price', 'quantity'])
bids = bids.astype(dtype= {'price':'float64','quantity':'float64'})
```

Esto nos genera el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    price   quantity
0   28962.0 17.682
1   28961.9 5.011
2   28961.6 0.452
3   28961.5 2.887
4   28949.1 0.036
5   28948.9 2.007
6   28948.8 0.500
7   28948.7 0.001
8   28918.2 0.016
9   28918.1 0.191
10  28918.0 0.019
11  28917.9 0.001
12  28855.9 0.086
13  28855.8 0.001
14  28855.6 0.018
15  28855.5 0.010
```

Para generar los rangos utilizamos `groupby` y `cut` y agregamos la suma de las columnas con `sum`

```
bids = bids.groupby(pd.cut(bids['price'], np.arange(bids['price'].min(), bids['price'].max() + 50, 50))).sum()
```

Esto devuelve:

```
                    price       quantity
price       
(28855.5, 28905.5]  86567.3     0.105
(28905.5, 28955.5]  231467.7    2.771
(28955.5, 29005.5]  115847.0    26.032
```

Comment: Excelente, muy claro! Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!